# How to understand Merge sort Algorithm(Recursive)

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

```
int sort(int a[],int n)
{
     int h;
     int b[n];
     h=n/2
     //copy a[] to b[]
     sort(b,n)
     sort(b+h, n-h)
     //merge two halves in b to a
     return;
}
```

In that code how can i understand sort(b,h) sort(b+h,n-h) part. what does it mean (b+h)??

Comment: `int b[n];` is not valid C++ because C++ does not allow variable length arrays. That only compiles because of a compiler extension.

Comment: `sort(b,n)` should be `sort(b,h)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays can decay to a pointer to the first element. In fact, when you pass an array to a function without passing it by reference, you're actually passing a pointer to the first element.

In the expression `b + h`, `b` decays to a pointer to the first element, and `b + h` is pointer arithmetic that results in a pointer pointing to the element at index `h`. `sort(b, h)` sorts the first `h` elements starting at the element `b` points to, which is the first half of the array. `sort(b + h, n - h)` sorts the `n - h` elements starting at the element `b + h` points to, which is the second half of the array.